# How can I compute this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have to prove that

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 && \cdots && 0 && a_{1,n+1} && \cdots && a_{1,2n} \\
\vdots && && \vdots && \vdots && && \vdots \\
0 && \cdots && 0 && a_{n,n+1} && \cdots && a_{n,2n} \\
a_{n+1,1} && \cdots && a_{n+1,n} && a_{n+1,n+1} && \cdots && a_{n+1,2n} \\
\vdots && && \vdots && \vdots && && \vdots \\
a_{2n,1} && \cdots && a_{2n,n} && a_{2n,n+1} && \cdots && a_{2n,2n}
\end{vmatrix}  \\
= (-1)^{n^2} \begin{vmatrix}
a_{1,n+1} \ \cdots \ a_{1,2n} \\
\  \ \vdots \\
a_{n,n+1} \ \cdots \ a_{n,2n}
\end{vmatrix} · \begin{vmatrix}
a_{n+1,1} \ \cdots \ a_{n+1,n} \\
\vdots \\
a_{2n,1} \ \cdots \ a_{2n,n}
\end{vmatrix}
$$

but I don't know exactly how to start with it. I guess that $(-1)^{n^2}$ is giving me some kind of clue on how to compute the determinant, as it's clear that $n$ is even and so is $n^2$. I would appreciate some hints on what should I do first of all and from there I will probably be able to get to the expression on the right.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0&B\\
C&D\\
\end{pmatrix}\right) = \operatorname{det}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
B&0\\
D&C\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0&I\\
I&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\right) = \operatorname{det}(B)\operatorname{det}(C)\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0&I\\
I&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\right) = \operatorname{det}(B)\operatorname{det}(C)(-1)^{n^2}$

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant).